# Defining symbolic matrix in Octave

Tags: matrix, octave, symbolic-math

When I execute the following code

```
pkg load symbolic
syms a 
A = [1,1,1,2;-1,0,-1,-1; -1,0,-2,-3; 1, 0, 1 ,a];
```

I receive the following error:

*ex12_1 error: octave_base_value::map_value(): wrong type argument 'scalar' error: called from
    ex12_1 at line 6 column 3*

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug. See [*bug#45423*](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45423) and [*bug#42152*](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42152).

The workaround is also suggested in the bug report which is to enclose each row in a square bracket. i.e.

```
A = [[ 1, 1,  1,  2]; 
     [-1, 0, -1, -1]; 
     [-1, 0, -2, -3]; 
     [ 1, 0,  1,  a]];
```

I have tested it to work on Octave v4.2.1, OctSymPy v2.6.0.

Comment: Are there other solutions?

Comment: @Rustam Please see the linked bug reports in the answer.